# Generate XMl File and upload the Xml file in the FTP server using FTp connection progrmatically

Tags: magento2

I have created custom XML file into a local server and connect FTP using programmatically in Magento 2 Now I want to upload that generated xml file into FTP server in specific location.but I need to upload in a particular directory How I can archive this?
Any idea related to this

thanks

Comment: You need to upload xml in different FTP? or same FTP?

Comment: @Ranganathan diffrent Ftp server, I have connect the Ftp server programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your xml file to another FTP using below code

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

class SftpActions
{
    protected $_sftp;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Io\Sftp $sftp
    ) {
        $this->_sftp = $sftp;
    }


    /**
     * @param obj $warehouse
     */
    public function saveFile( $data, $fileName, $exportedFolder )
    {
        $sftp = $this->loginSftp();

        foreach (explode('/', $exportedFolder) as $folder) {
            $sftp->chdir($folder);
        }

        $sftp->put($fileName ,$data);
    }

    /**
     * @return object $sftp
     */
    private function loginSftp()
    {
        $host = 'FTP Host';
        $port = 'FTP port';
        $username = 'username';
        $password = 'password';

        $this->_sftp->open(
            array(
                'host' => $host.':'$port,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password
            )
        );

        return $this->_sftp;
    }
}
```

You can call save function from above class by

```
$data = your xml data as string
$fileName will be your xml file name
$exportedFolder = your FTP folder from root
```

To create XML use below code..This is for order object.

```
<?php 
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\DomDocument\DomDocumentFactory $domFactory,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\SftpActions $sftpAction
){
    $this->_domFactory = $_domFactory;
    $this->_sftpAction = $sftpAction;
}

public function createXml(){
    $xmlDom = $this->_domFactory->create();
    $xmlDom->encoding = 'utf-8';
    $xmlDom->xmlVersion = '1.0';
    $xmlDom->formatOutput = true;

    $productsEntity = $xmlDom->createElement('products');

    $productcollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder');
    $_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');

    $searchCriteria = $productcollection->addFilter('color', 5434, 'eq')->create();
    $products = $_product->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
    $_updatedProducts = array();

    foreach($products as $sk => $sv) {
        // echo $_updatedProducts[$sk]["barcode"] = $sv->getSku();
        // echo $_updatedProducts[$sk]["name"] = $sv->getName();
        // echo $_updatedProducts[$sk]['description'] = $sv->getMetaDescription();
        // echo $_updatedProducts[$sk]['price'] = $sv->getPrice();
        // echo $_updatedProducts[$sk]['FreeStock'] = $sv->getQuantity();

        $productEntity = $xmlDom->createElement('product');

        $skuEntity = $xmlDom->createElement('barcode');
        $skuCdata = $xmlDom->createCDATASection($sv->getSku());
        $skuEntity->appendChild($skuCdata);
        $productEntity->appendChild($skuEntity);

        $nameEntity = $xmlDom->createElement('name');
        $nameCdata = $xmlDom->createCDATASection($sv->getSku());
        $nameEntity->appendChild($nameCdata);
        $productEntity->appendChild($nameEntity);

        $descEntity = $xmlDom->createElement('description');
        $descCdata = $xmlDom->createCDATASection($order->getCreatedAt());
        $descEntity->appendChild($descCdata);
        $productEntity->appendChild($descEntity);

        $priceEntity = $xmlDom->createElement('price');
        $priceCdata = $xmlDom->createCDATASection($order->getShippingDescription());
        $priceEntity->appendChild($priceCdata);
        $productEntity->appendChild($priceEntity);

        $stockEntity = $xmlDom->createElement('FreeStock');
        $stockCdata = $xmlDom->createCDATASection($order->getShippingDescription());
        $stockEntity->appendChild($stockCdata);
        $productEntity->appendChild($stockEntity);

        $productsEntity->appendChild($productEntity);

    }
    $xmlDom->appendChild($productsEntity);

    $saveOrder = $xmlDom->saveXML();

    $this->_sftpAction->save($saveOrder, 'test.xml', 'folder/path');
}
```

Comment: Ftp code is done, but How to create Xml file for the product collection and send it to different FTP server

Comment: Please check `saveFile` function. `$sftp->put($fileName ,$data);` this code will put the files

Comment: My query is to how to generate xml file for the product collection

Comment: foreach($products as $sk => $sv) {
   echo  $_updatedProducts[$i]["barcode"] = $sv->getSku();
    echo $_updatedProducts[$i]["name"] = $sv->getName();
    echo $_updatedProducts[$i]['description'] = $sv->getMetaDescription();
    echo $_updatedProducts[$i]['price'] = $sv->getPrice();
    echo $_updatedProducts[$i]['FreeStock'] = $sv->getQuantity();
    $i++;
 }
For this I have to generate the Xml file

Comment: Updated for order collection....understood about xml dom, and you can create for product

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response

Comment: Can you send me the code . For this I can check then implement into my requirement

Comment: Updated in this answer only please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102073/discussion-between-divya-and-ranganathan).

Comment: Can you please help me to solve this  issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298484/magento-2-validate-a-condition-rules-based-on-product-attribute/