# Magento 2 : Validate a condition rules based on product attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, validation, rules

How to validate a condition rules  based on product attribute  in magento  2

backend:

[image]

code:

```
    $product_id = '3';  // Crown Summit Backpack sku is 24-MB03
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $rules = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Rule')->getCollection();
    foreach ($rules as $rule) {
        $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
        $item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
        $item->setProduct($product);
        $validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($item);
    }
    var_dump($validate);
    var_dump($product);
```

Expected result is **false** but it always shows **true**. validation not done properly on product attributes.

`var_dump($validate);`

[image]

`var_dump($product);`

[image]

> Vendor\Module\Model\Rule.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;
/**
 * Class Rule
 * @package Vendor\Module\Model
 *
 * @method int|null getRuleId()
 * @method Rule setRuleId(int $id)
 */
class Rule extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * Prefix of model events names
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_module';
    /**
     * Parameter name in event
     *
     * In observe method you can use $observer->getEvent()->getRule() in this case
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';
    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory */
    protected $condCombineFactory;
    /** @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory */
    protected $condProdCombineF;
    /**
     * Store already validated addresses and validation results
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
     \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
     \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
       \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }
    /**
     * Set resource model and Id field name
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }
    /**
     * Get rule condition combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine
     */
      public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get rule condition product combine model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine
     */
    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condProdCombineF->create();
    }
    /**
     * Check cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     */
    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }
    /**
     * Set validation result for specific address to results cache
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @param bool $validationResult
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * Get cached validation result for specific address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return bool
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.BooleanGetMethodName)
     */
    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }
    /**
     * Return id for address
     *
     * @param Address $address
     * @return string
     */
    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }
}
```

**Finally i done it, here my updated  code**

```
public function execute()
    {  
      $validate  = array();
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $quoteId = $this->cart->getQuote()->getId();
      $quote =  $this->quoteFactory->load($quoteId);
      $fakeQuote = clone $quote;
      $fakeQuote->setId(null);
       $items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
       $rules = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Rule')->getCollection();
      foreach ($rules as $rule){
          foreach($items as $item){
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $quoteItem = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');
            $quoteItem->setQuote($fakeQuote)->setProduct($product);
            $quoteItem->setAllItems(array($product));
            $quoteItem->getProduct()->setProductId($product->getEntityId());
            $validate = $rule->getConditions()->validate($quoteItem);
        } 
    }
   // var_dump($validate); 
    return $validate;
    }
```

Comment: You need to check with all the cart items?

Comment: yes, i need to  check  with all cart item

Comment: Did you tried here with cart items? I think the issue is because you are sending product object instead of cart item object.

Comment: first of all  i tried static product object its not validate properly

Comment: I don't know about these...My assumption is you have to send cart item object...Let me try this with my env

Comment: Can you please try with my answer.. Add `24-MB03` product alone to check the rule.

Comment: $rule->getActions()->validate($item); always returns true. https://prnt.sc/qa76ze , https://prnt.sc/qa77hl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you validating your model (product) using the actions, but logically you should use the conditions, like:

```
$rule->getConditions()->validate($item);
```

Here is full code with changes:

```
$product_id = '3';  // Crown Summit Backpack sku is 24-MB03
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$rules = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Rule')->getCollection();
foreach ($rules as $rule) {
    $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);
    $item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
    $item->setProduct($product);
    $validate = $rule->getConditions()->validate($item);
}
var_dump($validate);
var_dump($product);
```

I think the `getActions()` is a conditions for the **Apply the rule to** (see the select below your main block) or other conditions in your model.

You can detect what you are using for validation pretty simple, just print out the `$rule->getConditions()->asStringRecursive()` and `$rule->getActions()->asStringRecursive()`. You must see which method returns desired conditions.

**PS:** the `$rule->getActions()->validate($item);` always returns **true** because empty conditions always means *the any item is valid*.

Comment: i used  $rule->getConditions()->validate($item)  but it reflects a error like `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\wamp64\www\m2\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found.php on line 65`

Comment: @divyasekar It mean that you have error somewhere in your model. The line 65 is `foreach ($model->getAllItems() as $item) {` so it try to work with you wrapper-model as with a Quote, but you set the Product. Try this: `$item = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');` then add item to quote and try to validate using quote.

Comment: i cant get you clearly , what i m understand of your suggestion is try with quote item instead of product if i m wright

Comment: @divyasekar Sorry, my english is not good enough :) Yes, you should try with a Quote object in which your product must be set as an quote item (you can use the `addItem` method). I will try to cover this issue more broadly in our blog article in future.

Comment: Thanks @Siarhey Uchukhlebau  i was done  it  by your suggestion

Comment: Thanks @SiarheyUchukhlebau it really helped me.

Comment: @divyasekar what did you do for Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\wamp64\www\m2\magento\vendor\magento\module-sales-rule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found.php on line 65 ?

Comment: I should try with a Quote object in which your product must be set as a quote item (I use the addItem method).

Comment: @DharmendraJadav you can check the above question, I was already updated a working code.

Comment: @DharmendraJadav  you refer a posted question on above or posted an answer on below. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

**Finally i done it, here my updated  code**

```
public function execute()
    {  
      $validate  = array();
      $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
      $quoteId = $this->cart->getQuote()->getId();
      $quote =  $this->quoteFactory->load($quoteId);
      $fakeQuote = clone $quote;
      $fakeQuote->setId(null);
       $items = $this->cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();
       $rules = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Rule')->getCollection();
      foreach ($rules as $rule){
          foreach($items as $item){
            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $quoteItem = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');
            $quoteItem->setQuote($fakeQuote)->setProduct($product);
            $quoteItem->setAllItems(array($product));
            $quoteItem->getProduct()->setProductId($product->getEntityId());
            $validate = $rule->getConditions()->validate($quoteItem);
        } 
    }
   // var_dump($validate); 
    return $validate;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with cart items using below code

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$items = $cart->getQuote()->getAllItems();

$rules = $objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Rule')->getCollection();

foreach($items as $item) {
    $validate = $rule->getActions()->validate($item);
}
var_dump($validate);
var_dump($product);
```

Comment: @divyasekar can you please update `Vendor\Module\Model\Rule` class code?

Comment: i update my code in the post

Comment: You are getting rules by `getCollection` but in `Siarhey Uchukhlebau` previous answer he is getting using `getRules`

Comment: i also used  a getting rules by getRules but  the validation not done properly

Comment: ok let me check

Comment: i was  done it sir. thank you so much for you help

Comment: Oh...good work.

Answer (score 0):

To validate products with rules we need to

```
// object manager to replace with properties created in __construct()
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

foreach ($products as $product) {
   $quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory')->create();
   $quote->setId(null);
        
   $quoteItem = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item');
   $quoteItem->setQuote($quote)->setProduct($product);
   $quoteItem->setAllItems([$product]);
   $quoteItem->getProduct()->setProductId($product->getEntityId());
      
   $result = $rule->getConditions()->validate($quoteItem);
   //$matched = !$result, result is false when it matches
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Method-1 by using getConditions()->validate()**

```
  protected $customConditionModel;
    protected $productFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        ....................................................
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomConditionFactory $customConditionModel,
        ....................................................
    ) {
        ....................................................
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->customConditionModel = $customConditionModel;
        ....................................................
    }
 
    public function checkCondition()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        $prdId = 6; //bag product id
        // Get product data by id
        $prdData = $this->productFactory->create()->load($prdId);
        // get rule collection
        $ruleColl = $this->customConditionModel->create()->getCollection();
        foreach ($ruleColl as $ruleKey => $ruleVal) {
            // check Product with condition
            if ($ruleVal->getConditions()->validate($prdData)) {
                echo "Rule Id " . $ruleVal->getId() . " Match<br/>";
            }
        }
    }
```

**Method-2 by using the Model function getMatchProductIds() which we already created.**

```
protected $customConditionModel;

public function __construct(
    ....................................................
    \VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\CustomConditionFactory $customConditionModel,
    ....................................................
) {
    ....................................................
    $this->customConditionModel = $customConditionModel;
    ....................................................

}

public function checkCondition()
{
    echo "<pre>";
    // get rule collection
    $ruleColl = $this->customConditionModel->create()->getCollection();
    foreach ($ruleColl as $ruleKey => $ruleVal) {
        // get all product's Ids with match with rule
        echo "***** Rule Id " . $ruleVal->getId() . " Match Product Ids ***** <br/>";
        $matchIds = array_values(array_unique($ruleVal->getMatchProductIds()));
        print_r($matchIds);
    }
}
```

**Model file give below:**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model;

use VendoreName\AddConditionFiled\Model\ResourceModel\CustomCondition as CustomConditionResourceModel;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;

class CustomCondition extends AbstractModel
{
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'VendoreName_addconditionfiled';
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';
    protected $condCombineFactory;
    protected $condProdCombineF;
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];
    protected $_selectProductIds;
    protected $_displayProductIds;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init(CustomConditionResourceModel::class);
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }

    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }

    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }

    public function getConditionsFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_conditions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getActionFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_actions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getMatchProductIds()
    {
        $productCollection = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection'
        );
        $productFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory'
        );
        $this->_selectProductIds = [];
        $this->setCollectedAttributes([]);
        $this->getConditions()->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);
        \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Iterator'
        )->walk(
            $productCollection->getSelect(),
            [[$this, 'callbackValidateProductCondition']],
            [
                'attributes' => $this->getCollectedAttributes(),
                'product' => $productFactory->create(),
            ]
        );
        return $this->_selectProductIds;
    }

    public function callbackValidateProductCondition($args)
    {
        $product = clone $args['product'];
        $product->setData($args['row']);
        $websites = $this->_getWebsitesMap();
        foreach ($websites as $websiteId => $defaultStoreId) {
            $product->setStoreId($defaultStoreId);
            if ($this->getConditions()->validate($product)) {
                $this->_selectProductIds[] = $product->getId();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _getWebsitesMap()
    {
        $map = [];
        $websites = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
            '\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface'
        )->getWebsites();
        foreach ($websites as $website) {
            if ($website->getDefaultStore() === null) {
                continue;
            }
            $map[$website->getId()] = $website->getDefaultStore()->getId();
        }
        return $map;
    }
}
```

[**Check Full Example click Here.**](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344615/82670)