# How to validate condition rule based on custom attribute(SKU)?

Tags: magento2

Does anyone have an idea of how to validate function works on product attribute while creating custom condition rule !?
I'm stuck in validating condition rule
Here, in my scenario, I've to validate my order's SKU with custom rule's saved condition SKU.
[image]
Any Advice?

I've referred and tried to apply [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298484/magento-2-validate-a-condition-rules-based-on-product-attribute) solution but doesn't work for me
Because in that case, she wants to fetch SKU from the cart (Quote) but in my case, I've to fetch SKU from ordered data that means sales_order_place_after. Maybe that doesn't make sense, I just have to understand that validate function with abstract model etc... The main thing is I'm stuck in that important concept of condition rule
Any solution or explanation regarding this?

Here's my model code

> Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Condition\Customer.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Condition;

class Customer extends \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Product\AbstractProduct
{

    protected function _addSpecialAttributes(array &$attributes)
    {
        parent::_addSpecialAttributes($attributes);
        $attributes['quote_item_qty'] = __('Quantity in cart');
        $attributes['quote_item_price'] = __('Price in cart');
        $attributes['quote_item_row_total'] = __('Row total in cart');

        $attributes['parent::category_ids'] = __('Category (Parent only)');
        $attributes['children::category_ids'] = __('Category (Children Only)');
    }

    public function getAttribute(): string
    {
        $attribute = $this->getData('attribute');
        if (strpos($attribute, '::') !== false) {
            list(, $attribute) = explode('::', $attribute);
        }

        return $attribute;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAttributeName()
    {
        $attribute = $this->getAttribute();
        if ($this->getAttributeScope()) {
            $attribute = $this->getAttributeScope() . '::' . $attribute;
        }

        return $this->getAttributeOption($attribute);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function loadAttributeOptions()
    {
        $productAttributes = $this->_productResource->loadAllAttributes()->getAttributesByCode();

        $attributes = [];
        foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute) {
            /* @var $attribute \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute */
            if (!$attribute->isAllowedForRuleCondition()
                || !$attribute->getDataUsingMethod($this->_isUsedForRuleProperty)
            ) {
                continue;
            }
            $frontLabel = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
            $attributes[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $frontLabel;
            $attributes['parent::' . $attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $frontLabel . __('(Parent Only)');
            $attributes['children::' . $attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $frontLabel . __('(Children Only)');
        }

        $this->_addSpecialAttributes($attributes);

        asort($attributes);
        $this->setAttributeOption($attributes);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAttributeElementHtml()
    {
        $html = parent::getAttributeElementHtml() .
            $this->getAttributeScopeElement()->getHtml();

        return $html;
    }

    private function getAttributeScopeElement(): \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement
    {
        return $this->getForm()->addField(
            $this->getPrefix() . '__' . $this->getId() . '__attribute_scope',
            'hidden',
            [
                'name' => $this->elementName . '[' . $this->getPrefix() . '][' . $this->getId() . '][attribute_scope]',
                'value' => $this->getAttributeScope(),
                'no_span' => true,
                'class' => 'hidden',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getFormName(),
            ]
        );
    }

    public function setAttribute(string $value)
    {
        if (strpos($value, '::') !== false) {
            list($scope, $attribute) = explode('::', $value);
            $this->setData('attribute_scope', $scope);
            $this->setData('attribute', $attribute);
        } else {
            $this->setData('attribute', $value);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function loadArray($arr)
    {
        parent::loadArray($arr);
        $this->setAttributeScope($arr['attribute_scope'] ?? null);

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function asArray(array $arrAttributes = [])
    {
        $out = parent::asArray($arrAttributes);
        $out['attribute_scope'] = $this->getAttributeScope();

        return $out;
    }
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine.php

```
<?php
 
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Condition;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection;
 
class Combine extends \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Combine
{
  
    protected $_ruleConditionProd;

  
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Rule\Model\Condition\Context $context,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product $ruleConditionProduct,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_ruleConditionProd = $ruleConditionProduct;
        $this->setType(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine::class);
    }

    
    public function getNewChildSelectOptions()
    {
        $productAttributes = $this->_ruleConditionProd->loadAttributeOptions()->getAttributeOption();
        $pAttributes = [];
        $iAttributes = [];
        foreach ($productAttributes as $code => $label) {
            if (strpos($code, 'quote_item_') === 0) {
                $iAttributes[] = [
                    'value' => \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product::class . '|' . $code,
                    'label' => $label,
                ];
            } else {
                $pAttributes[] = [
                    'value' => \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product::class . '|' . $code,
                    'label' => $label,
                ];
            }
        }

        $conditions = parent::getNewChildSelectOptions();
        $conditions = array_merge_recursive(
            $conditions,
            [
                [
                    'value' => \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine::class,
                    'label' => __('Conditions Combination'),
                ],
                ['label' => __('Cart Item Attribute'), 'value' => $iAttributes],
                ['label' => __('Product Attribute'), 'value' => $pAttributes]
            ]
        );
        return $conditions;
    }

    /**
     * Collect validated attributes
     *
     * @param Collection $productCollection
     * @return $this
     */
    public function collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection)
    {
        foreach ($this->getConditions() as $condition) {
            $condition->collectValidatedAttributes($productCollection);
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @since 101.0.6
     */
    protected function _isValid($entity)
    {
        if (!$this->getConditions()) {
            return true;
        }

        $all = $this->getAggregator() === 'all';
        $true = (bool)$this->getValue();

        foreach ($this->getConditions() as $cond) {
            if ($entity instanceof \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel) {
                $validated = $this->validateEntity($cond, $entity);
            } else {
                $validated = $cond->validateByEntityId($entity);
            }
            if ($all && $validated !== $true) {
                return false;
            } elseif (!$all && $validated === $true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return $all ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Validate entity.
     *
     * @param object $cond
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $entity
     * @return bool
     */
    private function validateEntity($cond, \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $entity)
    {
        $true = (bool)$this->getValue();
        $validated = !$true;
        foreach ($this->retrieveValidateEntities($cond->getAttributeScope(), $entity) as $validateEntity) {
            $validated = $cond->validate($validateEntity);
            if ($validated === $true) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return $validated;
    }

 
    private function retrieveValidateEntities($attributeScope, \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel $entity)
    {
        if ($attributeScope === 'parent') {
            $validateEntities = [$entity];
        } elseif ($attributeScope === 'children') {
            $validateEntities = $entity->getChildren() ?: [$entity];
        } else {
            $validateEntities = $entity->getChildren() ?: [];
            $validateEntities[] = $entity;
        }

        return $validateEntities;
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Rule.php

```
    <?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;

class Rule extends AbstractModel
{

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_module';

    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';
    protected $objectManager;

    protected $condCombineFactory;

    protected $condProdCombineF;


    protected $validatedAddresses = [];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Rule');
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id');
    }


    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->objectManager->create('Vendor\Module\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine');
    }

    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine');
    }
 
    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }
 
    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Module\Model\Validator.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Magento\Framework\DataObject;
use Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

class Validator extends DataObject
{
    protected $rateAdjustments = [];

    protected $objectManager;

    private $appState;

    public function __construct(ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager, State $appState, array $data = [])
    {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->appState = $appState;
        parent::__construct($data);
    }

    public function init($request)
    {
        $this->setRequest($request);
        return $this;
    }
```

My Updated code... in if condition I'm checking whether the flag variable is true or false but it stops the execution from validate the condition
$ruleConditionData prints my rule data also

Array ( [rule_id] => 1 [name] => update4 [is_active] => 1 [stores] => 2 [customer_groups] => 0  [conditions_serialized] => {"type":"Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all","conditions":[{"type":"Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product","attribute":"sku","operator":"==","value":"similar more","is_value_processed":false,"attribute_scope":""}]} )

```
 public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
  $flag = false;
    if ($this->helper->isEnabled()) {

        $orderIds = $observer->getOrderIds();
        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->load($orderIds[0]);
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
            $itemSku = $orderItem->getSku();
           
            $ruleId = 1;

            $prdData = $this->productloader->create()->loadByAttribute("sku", $itemSku );

            $ruleConditionData = $this->ruleFactory->create()->load($ruleId);
           
            print_r($ruleConditionData->getData());
          
                if ($ruleConditionData->getConditions()->validate($prdData)) {
                $flag = true;
               
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Please share your Model file and your code.

Comment: Please check my updated question!

Comment: Your rule value are store into your custom table or not ?

Comment: Yes... my rule value is stored in my custom table in serialized form

Comment: {"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Combine","attribute":null,"operator":null,"value":"1","is_value_processed":null,"aggregator":"all","conditions":[{"type":"Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product","attribute":"sku","operator":"==","value":"similar more","is_value_processed":false,"attribute_scope":""}]}

It's stored like this

Comment: Data is stored in the database, I can retrieve in grid and log also ....may be I'm very near to the end but I think I stuck in the important part of condition rule validating :( ...

Answer (score 1):

> **Try this code**

```
protected $ruleFactory;
protected $productloader;

public function __construct(
    ...........................................
    \Vendor\Module\Model\RuleFactory $ruleFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productloader,
    ...........................................
) {
    ...........................................
    $this->ruleFactory = $ruleFactory;
    $this->productloader = $productloader;
    ...........................................
}

public function execute()
{
    ...........................................
    ...........................................

    
    $selectedValue = "SKU-Product";
    $prdData = $this->productloader->create()->loadByAttribute("sku", $selectedValue);

    $ruleId = 1 ;

    $ruleConditionData = $this->ruleFactory->create();
    $ruleConditionData->load($ruleId);
    //$ruleConditionData->getConditions()->validate($prdData);

    if ($ruleConditionData->getConditions()->validate($prdData)) {
        echo "Rule Match";
    }  else {
        echo "Rule Not Match";
    }
}
```

> **Update your Rule.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Rule as RuleResourceModel;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
use Magento\Rule\Model\AbstractModel;

class Rule extends AbstractModel
{
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_module';
    protected $_eventObject = 'rule';
    protected $condCombineFactory;
    protected $condProdCombineF;
    protected $validatedAddresses = [];

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface $localeDate,
        \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\Condition\CombineFactory $condCombineFactory,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\CombineFactory $condProdCombineF,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->condCombineFactory = $condCombineFactory;
        $this->condProdCombineF = $condProdCombineF;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $localeDate, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init(RuleResourceModel::class);
        $this->setIdFieldName('rule_id'); // add your table primari key 
    }

    public function getConditionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function getActionsInstance()
    {
        return $this->condCombineFactory->create();
    }

    public function hasIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? true : false;
    }
 
    public function setIsValidForAddress($address, $validationResult)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] = $validationResult;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getIsValidForAddress($address)
    {
        $addressId = $this->_getAddressId($address);
        return isset($this->validatedAddresses[$addressId]) ? $this->validatedAddresses[$addressId] : false;
    }

    private function _getAddressId($address)
    {
        if ($address instanceof Address) {
            return $address->getId();
        }
        return $address;
    }

    public function getConditionsFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_conditions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }

    public function getActionFieldSetId($formName = '')
    {
        return $formName . 'rule_actions_fieldset_' . $this->getId();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply...  :)
Can I use this code in customer.php file directly?

Comment: your problem is solve or not  ?

Comment: At first, really appreciate your solution!... I used this code and I'm stuck in one error ...

Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\mag233\vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product.php:59

Comment: conditions validation is works or not ?

Comment: Noo it stops in validate function

Comment: in $prddata it gets all data but still, it displays error like


Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTypeId() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\mag233\vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product.php:59

Comment: Please update your code into your Question.. for more details.

Comment: Yeah...I've updated my code

Comment: Which call you are using in ruleFactory ?

Comment: Vendor/Module/Model/RuleFactory... I've Rule Directory and it prints Rule 1 Data also...

Comment: I tried to print rule data using this...  print_r($ruleConditionData->getData()); and it fethces all data of Rule 1

Comment: I can get Rule data, Product data and all needed items you've answered in the code... But don't know Why it throws error

Comment: Is there any need to call validate function in any other files?... According to  my research, I got to know that we can use that validate function directly in the file in which validation should be perform

Comment: Please check your rule.php file i update into answer please check and update me.

Comment: Yeah.. Thank you so much for your efforts toward this issue... One update is there... if I use getActions instead of getConditions then it doesn't show error... Is it proper?

Comment: your can use if your condition works the you can use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116801/discussion-between-denlier1211-and-msquare).